# C# visual basic express, how do i check if backspace or esc is pressed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, keyboard

I'm new to C# and am coding a basic console application with a main menu. When in a part of the program I'd like the user to be able to press backspace to be able to return to main menu or press ESC to quit the program.

How can I tell if the backspace and ESC are pressed?

I assume its not a simple as detected letters and numbers?

for example id like:

```
    // Press backspace to go back to main menu or press esc to exit program
    Console.WriteLine("Press BACKSPACE to return to main menu, or ESC to quit.");
    if(backspace.ispressed )
    {
      menuOption = Console.ReadLine();

    }else if(esc.ispressed){

      Environment.Exit(0)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Console.ReadKey() to detect the key being pressed

```
Console.WriteLine("Press BACKSPACE to return to main menu, or ESC to quit.");
ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
{
    menuOption = Console.ReadLine();

}else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape){

    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I have no errors but it isn't recognising when those keys are pressed, and not changing a variable when backspace is pressed to take me back to main menu

Answer (score 2):

Asuming that you are in a WinForms environment you need to bind to a KeyDown event on a control. For example if you want to check it on a TextBox element you can do the following:

```
this.TextSearch.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.TextSearchKeyDown)
private void TextSearchKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
     {
         // Do stuff
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

look at this page on [Console.ReadKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx)

Example:

```
var cki = Console.ReadKey();
if(cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
    Environment.Exit(0)
}
else if(if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
{
    menuOption = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx

The code here is using Console.ReadKey() to fill a key object and then checking the .key attribute against ConsoleKey.Escape

Documentation for ConsoleKey here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekey.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
 ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
 keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();
 if (keyinfo == Keys.Esc || keyinfo == keys.Backspace)
```

Should do it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
    // do something
}
if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
{
    // do something
}
```